# Getting file form Restlet Response

Tags: android, file, restlet

I created webapp which sends file by FileRepresentation. Client is an Android app. How can I get File from Restlet Response object on the client side?

Comment: Follow this: http://codedmi.com/questions/3615152/how-to-get-response-from-restlet-clientresource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file content will be present within the payload. So you can extract it like any payload with Restlet, as described below:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(...);
Representation rep = cr.get();
```

In fact, the `FileRepresentation` class is provided in order to fill request / response from a file but can't be used to extract content of a response.

To have access to your response content on the client side, it depends on the file type. If you receive an ascii content, you can do something like that:

```
Representation representation = cr.get();
String fileContent = representation.getText();
```

If it's a binary file, you need to work with a stream, as described below:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
cr.get().write(outputStream);
byte[] fileContent = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: But what is resource?

Comment: Sorry! It's a typo: `resource` should be `cr`. I updated my answer. Hope that it's clearer now ;-)